# Version queries in URL to bypass browser cache

Tags: web, browser-cache

I'm writing a web application which will likely be updated frequently, including changes to css and js files which are typically cached aggressively by the browser.

In order for changes to become instantly visible to users, without affecting cache performance, I've come up with the following system:

Every resource file has a version.  This version is appended with a ? sign, e.g. main.css becomes main.css?v=147.  If I change a file, I increment the version in all references.  (In practice I would probably just have a script to increment the version for all resources, every time I deploy an update.)

My questions are:

1. Is this a reasonable approach for production code?  Am I missing something?  (Or is there a better way?)
2. Does the question mark introduce additional overhead?  I could incorporate the version number into the filename, if that is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The approach sound reasonable.  Here are some points to consider:

- If you have many different resource files with different version numbers it might be quite some overhead for developers to correctly manage all these and increase them in the correct situations.

  - You might need to implement a policy for your team
  - or write a CI task to check that the devs did it right
- You could use one version number for all files.  For example when you have a version number of the whole app you could use that.

  - It makes "managing" the versions  for developers a no-op.
  - It changes the links on *every* deploy

Depending on the number of resource files you have to manage the frequency of deploys vs. the frequency of deploys that change a resource file and the numbers of requests for these resource files one or the other solution might be more performant.  This is a question of trade off.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.  Yes, I believe having one global version which is incremented on each deployment is the simplest and most effective for now, as the project is still fairly small.